How to Implement noindex tags at scale in Magento (particularly with Wildcards)
Good afternoon,
I am wondering if there is a way to implement no index tags at scale in magento, much like you would in robots.txt with wildcard selectors. Example:
example.com/catalogsearch/*
Whereby I'm noindexing all urls that begin with "/catalogsearch/" and end with any value.
I could have accomplished this prior to the site being indexed in robots.txt unfortunately my tenure does not date back that far and now I'm doing cleanup.
